# WPF: Get Property that a control is Bound to in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to find a way to get the Property to which a control is bound (in c#).

If I have the following:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit DisplayMember="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NameOptions, Mode=OneTime}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I am now trying to get the location to which the SelectedItem is bound to, i.e. the result should be "Name". Then in code I need to do some stuff with that ViewModel Property. Issue is that I can't just hard code this as it is a generic method that needs to work with each control on the form.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
BindingExpression be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression((FrameworkElement)yourComboBox, ((DependencyProperty)Button.SelectedItemProperty));
string Name = be.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
```

[To give credit where it's due.](https://web.archive.org/web/20111008212650/http://blog.spencen.com/2008/05/02/how-to-get-a-list-of-bindings-in-wpf.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into using [`BindingExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.aspx)

IE:

```
var bindingExpression = this.myComboBox.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedItem);
string bindingPath = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path.Path
```

I see you're using a DXE ComboBox instead of a standard - expecting it derives from a normal .NET control object, you should still have this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried both approaches and both worked. And works fine on the dxe ComboBox. Thanks.