# How to get property columns shown on DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid that displays only certain properties of a class.

What I would like to do is, get a List of the bound properties in column order, how can I achieve this?

One more thing, I would only want the visible columns.

[EDIT]

The following is what I use to search for text within class properties, at the moment it searches through all properties.

This will change to search for only properties that are visible on the DataGrid

```
public static class FullTextSearch<T>
{

    public static bool Match(T item, string searchTerm)
    {
        bool match = _properties.Select(prop => prop(item)).Any(value => value != null && value.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
        return match;
    }

    private static List<Func<T, string>> _properties;

    public static void FullTextSearchInit()
    {
        _properties = GetPropertyFunctions().ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetPropertyFunctions()
    {
        var stringProperties = GetStringPropertyFunctions();
        var intProperties = GetIntPropertyFunctions();
        var decimalProperties = GetDecimalPropertyFunctions();
        var dateTimeProperties = GetDateTimePropertyFunctions();
        return stringProperties.Concat(decimalProperties).Concat(intProperties).Concat(dateTimeProperties);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetStringPropertyFunctions()
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)).ToList();

        var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetStringPropertyFunc);
        return properties;
    }

    public static Func<T, string> GetStringPropertyFunc(PropertyInfo propInfo)
    {
        ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression<Func<T, string>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
        Func<T, string> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
        return propertyAccessor;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetIntPropertyFunctions()
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(int)).ToList();

        var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetIntPropertyFunc);
        return properties;
    }

    public static Func<T, string> GetIntPropertyFunc(PropertyInfo propInfo)
    {
        ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression<Func<T, int>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
        Func<T, int> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
        return (T item) => propertyAccessor(item).ToString();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetDecimalPropertyFunctions()
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal)).ToList();

        var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetDecimalPropertyFunc);
        return properties;
    }

    public static Func<T, string> GetDecimalPropertyFunc(PropertyInfo propInfo)
    {
        ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression<Func<T, decimal>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, decimal>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
        Func<T, decimal> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
        return (T item) => propertyAccessor(item).ToString();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetDateTimePropertyFunctions()
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)).ToList();

        var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetDateTimePropertyFunc);
        return properties;
    }

    public static Func<T, string> GetDateTimePropertyFunc(PropertyInfo propInfo)
    {
        ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
        Func<T, DateTime> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
        return (T item) => propertyAccessor(item).ToString();
    }
}
```

The code below is how I call it, it finds all the properties that match the search value and add the items to a list, this list is processed and added to the SelectedItems property on the DataGrid.

In the long run I would like to make this generic enough to have on any DataGrid. So instead of searching through all properties, it needs to get more specific and if I want to provide next and previous search functionality, to go to the next or previous cell match I need to get these properties in the order that matches the DataGrid columns.

Eventually I'd like to remove the hard-coded class name when I call:
FullTextSearch<UserViewModel>.FullTextSearchInit();
and
FullTextSearch<UserViewModel>.Match()
but this will be another question

```
string sv = SearchValue;
this.Target.SelectedItems.Clear();

var itemsSource = this.Target.Items as IEnumerable;

List<Object> tempItems = new List<Object>();

FullTextSearch<UserViewModel>.FullTextSearchInit();

if (itemsSource != null)
{
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
        if (FullTextSearch<UserViewModel>.Match((UserViewModel)item, sv))
        {
            tempItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
    if (tempItems.Count > 0)
    {
        //Add found items to SelectedItems
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Do you want to get the name of the properties bound to the DataGrid?

Comment: What prevents you from accessing the class which contains said properties?

Comment: Getting the properties out of the class is something I know how to do, however I do not want all the properties out of the class, just the ones that are visible on the DataGrid.

Comment: The datagrid has a Columns collection.  Those should be the visible columns. EDIT: I guess you'd want to look at the Visibility property of each column.

Comment: Then you'd look at the bindings to see which properties are bound to those columns.

Comment: @NielW ok Ryan has shown me how to get which column are visible. I will pop that into a foreach. How to find the bound property.

Comment: @Hank http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767557/wpf-get-property-that-a-control-is-bound-to-in-code-behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps:

```
var visibleColumns = grid.Columns.Where(c => c.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible).ToList();
```

Comment: It does thanks, I will use a foreach to loop through these, any ideas on how to find the property bound to the column?

Comment: Well, is there any way I could get you to post an example of your code? I think I might know what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes no problem give me a second

Comment: @Hank, I'm sorry I haven't responded to this question yet; I've been caught up with something else at work. Are you still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: Me too, yes, I've found out how to the binding, just trying to figure out how to get only textual type columns and then its sorted